# Find contact name by phone number in Android service (Delphi + Firemonkey)

Tags: android, delphi, service, firemonkey, contacts

How can i find contact name by phone number in Android service (Delphi + Firemonkey)?

Delphi Tokyo + Firemonkey (FMX).

I can not understand, why wSubCursor.getCount returns 0?

The phone number in the address book is exactly present.

The function is executed inside the service.

```
function GetContactByPhoneNumber(const sTel: string): string;
var
  wJDislpayName,
  wJFirstName,
  wJLastName,
  wJQueryStr: JString;
  wJQueryParams: TJavaObjectArray<JString>;

  wSubCursor: JCursor;
  wfilter: TJavaObjectArray<JString>;
  wDataUri: JNet_URI;
begin  
  wDataUri := TJContactsContract_Data.JavaClass.CONTENT_URI;

  wfilter := TJavaObjectArray<JString>.Create(3);
  wfilter[0] := TJCommonDataKinds_StructuredName.JavaClass.DISPLAY_NAME;
  wfilter[1] := TJCommonDataKinds_StructuredName.JavaClass.FAMILY_NAME;
  wfilter[2] := TJCommonDataKinds_StructuredName.JavaClass.GIVEN_NAME;

  wJQueryStr := StringToJString('mimetype = ? AND lookup = ?');

  wJQueryParams := TJavaObjectArray<JString>.Create(2);
  wJQueryParams[0] := TJCommonDataKinds_Phone.JavaClass.NUMBER;
  wJQueryParams[1] := StringToJString(sTel);

  wSubCursor := TAndroidHelper.Context.getContentResolver.Query(wDataUri, wfilter, wJQueryStr, wJQueryParams, nil);

  try
    if wSubCursor.getCount > 0 then
    begin
      // Getting only first row, as we retrieving only names, a contact can have only one first name, one familyname,
      // for phone number for example, we need to loop on each row (while (wSubCursor.moveToNext) do) because a contact can have many phone number

      wSubCursor.moveToNext;
      wJDislpayName := wSubCursor.getString(0);
      wJLastName    := wSubCursor.getString(1);
      wJFirstName   := wSubCursor.getString(2);
    end;

    Result := JStringToString(wJDislpayName);
  finally
    wSubCursor.close;
    FreeAndNil(wSubCursor);// := nil;
  end;
end;
```

Thanx

Answer (score 0):

```
function GetContactByNumbers(const aPhoneNumbers: TList<String>): string;
var
  wUri: JNet_URI;
  lookupID: String;
  wCursor,
  wSubCursor: JCursor;
  wLookup_Idx: Integer;
  wDisplayNameIdx: integer;
  wfilter,
  wJQueryParams: TJavaObjectArray<JString>;
  wDataUri: JNet_URI;
begin
  wUri :=  TJContactsContract_Contacts.JavaClass.CONTENT_URI;
  wCursor := TAndroidHelper.Context.getContentResolver.query(wUri, nil, nil, nil, StringToJString('display_name ASC'));
   try
     wLookup_Idx := wCursor.getColumnIndex(StringToJString('lookup'));
     wDisplayNameIdx := wCursor.getColumnIndex(StringToJString('display_name'));

     while wCursor.moveToNext do
     begin
       lookupID := JStringToString(wCursor.getString(wLookup_Idx));
       wfilter := TJavaObjectArray<JString>.Create(1);
       wfilter[0] := TJCommonDataKinds_Phone.JavaClass.NUMBER;

       // Query condition (Extract only data for specific ID)
       wJQueryParams := TJavaObjectArray<JString>.Create(2);
       wJQueryParams[0] := TJCommonDataKinds_Phone.JavaClass.CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE;
       wJQueryParams[1] := StringToJString(lookupID);

       wDataUri := TJContactsContract_Data.JavaClass.CONTENT_URI;  // Contacts data uri

       wSubCursor := TAndroidHelper.Context.getContentResolver.
         Query(wDataUri,wfilter,StringToJString('mimetype = ? AND lookup = ?') , wJQueryParams,nil); // Exec query

       try
         if wSubCursor.getCount > 0 then
         begin
           while (wSubCursor.moveToNext) do
           begin
             if aPhoneNumbers.Contains(JStringToString(wSubCursor.getString(0))) then
             begin
               Result := JStringToString(wCursor.getString(wDisplayNameIdx));
               Break;
             end;
           end;
         end;
       finally
         wSubCursor.close;
         wSubCursor := nil;
       end;
     end;
   finally
     wCursor.Close;
     wCursor := nil;
   end;
end;
```

Answer (score 0):

From:
http://www.sql.ru/forum/1183758-2/dobavit-kontakt-v-android-address-book

work for me try with:

```
function TContactsManager.GetContactByNumber(
 const aPhoneNumber: string): string;
var
 wUri: JNet_URI;
 wCursor: JCursor;
 wfilter,
 wJQueryParams: TJavaObjectArray<JString>;
begin
 Result := '';
 wUri := TJNet_URI.JavaClass.withAppendedPath
(
 TJContactsContract_PhoneLookup.JavaClass.CONTENT_FILTER_URI,
 StringToJString(aPhoneNumber)
);

  wfilter := TJavaObjectArray<JString>.Create(2);
  wfilter[0] := StringToJString('lookup');
  wfilter[1] := StringToJString('display_name');

 with SharedActivity.getContentResolver do
  wCursor := query(wUri, wfilter, nil, nil, nil);

try
   if Assigned(wCursor) and
   (wCursor.getCount > 0) then
  begin
  wCursor.moveToNext;
  Result := JStringToString(wCursor.getString(
    wCursor.getColumnIndex(StringToJString('display_name'))));
  end;
finally
wCursor.Close;
wCursor := nil;
end;
end;

enter code here
```